# Xsd.exe generating wrong C# classes when inheriting enumeration

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

Is this a bug?

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:simpleType name="sbrSexItemType">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="3"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="0"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="TestSexItemType1" type="sbrSexItemType"/>
    <xsd:element name="TestSexItemType2" type="sbrSexItemType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

And I get:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("TestSexItemType1", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public enum sbrSexItemType {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2")]
    Item2,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("3")]
    Item3,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("0")]
    Item0,
}
```

Is this some kind of joke? Not even an error was generated. How does the generated code represent the XSD in any shape or form?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the possible values `1,2,3,0` can't be directly translated to enum values (Identifiers can't start with a number), so xsd puts "`Item`" before the value when creating the identifier. The `XmlEnumAttribute` tells the `XmlSerializer` which value should actually be used when reading or writing an Xml file. So it looks like the generated enum does the job.

Comment: No, my point is instead of generating "TestSexItemType1" type, it generates the enum and specify the root element to "look like" the type. Then it completely ignores "TestSexItemType2" as if tho it doesn't exist?...

Comment: @SleeperSmith There should be a class though for the complete xsd. How does that look like?

Comment: No there isn't. That's everything.

Answer (score 0):

if you have other types rather than enum. You should put the enum at the top. I don't know why but my problem was solved like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've put the two types that inherit from the enum, still no luck.